# PHP explode group_concat

Tags: php, mysql

How  can i explode `[group_concat(DISTINCT LineItem.ItemID)] => 600278,WH1502`.

I tried this but displays nothing

```
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT ...")

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) { 
$r = $row[LineItem.ItemID];
 explode(',',$r);
}
```

Also tried

```
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT ...")

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
   $r = $row[group_concat(DISTINCT LineItem.ItemID)];
   explode(',',$r);
 }
```

//ARRAY

```
  Array ( 
        [0] => XXOR001# 
        [CustomerID] => XXOR001# 
        [1] => XXXX INDUSTRIES 
        [Customer_Bill_Name] => XXX INDUSTRIES 
        [2] => WILL CALL [WhichShipVia] => WILL CALL [3] => 
        [INV_POSOOrderNumber] => [4] => 2014-12-05 
        [ShipByDate] => 2014-12-05 [5] => 
        [GoodThruDate] => [6] => 
        [CustomerSONo] => [7] => 15001 
        [Reference] => 15001 [8] => 2014-11-17 
        [TransactionDate] => 2014-11-17 [9] => 1 
        [DistNumber] => 1 
        [10] => 30.0000000000000000000 
        [Quantity] => 30.0000000000000000000 
        [11] => 600278,WH1502 
        [group_concat(DISTINCT LineItem.ItemID)] => 600278,WH1502 
        [12] => ASSY400/60-15.5/14 TRCIMP 15.5X13 8-8 FLAT, BW (TW4155-2)  
        [SalesDescription] => ASSY400/60-15.5/14 TRCIMP 15.5X13 8-8 FLAT, BW (TW4155-2)
        [13] => TW4155-2 
        [PartNumber] => TW4155-2 [14] => ASSY400/60-15.5/14W/WHL15.5X13 
        [ItemDescription] => ASSY400/60-15.5/14W/WHL15.5X13 )
```

Comment: Change your `group_concat(DISTINCT LineItem.ItemID)` in your `SELECT` query to an alias -> `group_concat(DISTINCT LineItem.ItemID) as ItemIDgroup`, then use the alias in the explode -> `$r = $row['ItemIDgroup']; explode(',',$r);`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure what you are trying to do, but you could try something like this to help provide some visibility to your code:

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) { 
    $r = $row[LineItem.ItemID];
    $lineItemArray = explode(',',$r);
    print_r($lineItemArray);
}
```

[**explode()**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) creates an array from a string based on the assigned separator. Consider this example:

```
$r = '600278,WH1502';
$rarray = explode(',',$r);
print_r($rarray);

//Output:
Array
(
    [0] => 600278
    [1] => WH1502
)
```

[**See demo**](http://codepad.org/DdirpbSq)

Comment: Thanks Mark How can i store the field `LineItem.ItemID` in `$r` instead of `$r = '600278,WH1502';`?

Comment: Thanks Mark but I dont get it why doesnt print `$lineItemArray`. I tried exactly the same the code you put above.